# How to test if a file is readable in python without opening the file?

Tags: python

Would like to test if a file is readable in python on a linux system by checking its attributes/permissions.

New to python and I am looking for the equivalent of the following from  perl/bash.

[[ -r ${filename} ]]

or

if ( -r $filename ) {...}

I just do an open on the file to check if its readable:

```
def isFileReadable2 (filename):
    # check to see if file is readable
    # by trying to open a file in readonly mode
    # if an exception occurs,
    # then either the file didnt exist, or file was NOT readable
    try:
        import stat
        mode = os.stat(filename).st_mode
        fh = open (filename, 'r')
    except IOError as err:
        print ("Error opening file {}:{}\n". format (filename, err))
    else:
        fh.close ()
        return True
    return False
```

I did notice that stat_result's bit pattern corresponded to the files
permissions, i.e. st_mode=32832 translates to 0b1000000001000000,
which in turn tells me that this file is user executable only, and not
readable at all, which happens to be correct.

So, while I could check using the proper bit masks, is there a better
portable interface to the os.stat_result object? and in particular the st_mode
value?

Thought of using os.fstat, but that returns the same stat_result object.

tia,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the function `os.access`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access).

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. I understand the danger mentioned, but need to pre check anyway.